# Pandas DataFrame exhibits odd behaviour when setting row

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two pieces of code

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame([('a', 1)], columns=['col1', 'col2']))
df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame([('b', 2)], columns=['col1', 'col2']))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([('c', 3), ('d', 4)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df1.iloc[0] = df2.loc[df2['col1'] == 'c']

print(df1)
```

and

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame([('a', 1)], columns=['col1', 'col2']))
df1 = df1.append(pd.DataFrame([('b', 2)], columns=['col1', 'col2']))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([('c', 3), ('d', 4)], columns=['col1', 'col2'])

df1[[]]

df1.iloc[0] = df2.loc[df2['col1'] == 'c']

print(df1)
```

They are identical except for the line `df1[[]]` appearing in the latter. I would expect their outputs to be the same; however, the first outputs

```
                               col1                             col2
0  0    c
Name: col1, dtype: object  0    3
Name: col2, dtype: int64
0                                 b                                2
```

and the second outputs

```
  col1 col2
0    c    3
0    b    2
```

Is this expected behaviour? If so, why are the two outputs different? Thanks!

(I'm running pandas version 1.3.2 with Python 3.9.9.)

Comment: That's a tricky question. Here's what I've figured out so far: 1) The way you construct the dataframe matters. The dataframe `df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b'], 'col2': [1, 2]}, columns=['col1', 'col2'], index=[0, 0])` is semantically equivalent, but does not trigger the same issue. Calling `.copy()` on the dataframe also prevents the issue. 2) It seem to be related to the BlockManager somehow. `df[[]]` calls `df1.take(indices=[], axis=1)`, which calls `df1._consolidate_inplace()`, which consolidates from 2 ObjectBlocks to 1. That triggers the issue.